# vueUse createFetch is not returning a function that can be awaited

Tags: vuejs3, vueuse

I am trying to use createFetch to create a pre-configured useFetch function. Later, in a Pinia store action I use await to invoke the function to call an API. The defining functions is as follows:

```js
import { createFetch } from "@vueuse/core";
import { ref } from "vue";

const token = ref("");

export function defineServer(baseUrl, options = {}) {
  return createFetch({
    baseUrl,
    options: {
      ...options,
      beforeFetch(ctx) {
        ctx.options.headers.Authorization = token.value;
        return ctx;
      },
      afterFetch(ctx) {
        const header = ctx.response.headers.get("Authorization");
        token.value = header ? header : "";
        return ctx;
      },
    },
    fetchOptions: {
      mode: "cors",
    },
  });
}
```

The Pinia store code is as follows:

```js
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import { defineServer } from "@/js/poster.js";

const authServer = defineServer("https://localhost/auth-server");

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
  state: () => {
    return {
      signedIn: false,
      mode: "Login",
      user: { email: "", firstName: "", lastName: "" },
    };
  },
  getters: {
    credential(state) {
      if (state.signedIn) {
        return `${state.user.firstName} ${state.user.lastName} (${state.user.role})`;
      } else return "Guest";
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async signin() {
      const data = await authServer("login")
        .post({
          email: "myname@eample.com",
          password: "password",
        })
        .json().data;
      this.signedIn = true;
      console.log(data);
      const credentials = data.msg.split("|");
      this.user.email = credentials[0];
      this.user.firstName = credentials[1];
      this.user.lastName = credentials[2];
      this.user.role = credentials[3];
      return;
    },
  }
}
```

Although I'm using await to call authServer, it returns immediately and consequently the data is undefined. I can see the call does return the expected data but too late; What should I be doing to make the call properly async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) function returns a Promise that needs to be awaited separately. You'll need to split your current authServer call into two statements:

```js
const response = await authServer("login").post({
  email: "myname@eample.com",
  password: "password"
})
const data = await response.json().data
```

Comment: Thankyou! Just the same as a normal Fetch then; I should have thought of that.